# Launch a pthread with a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, std-function, stdbind

For reasons outside of my control, I have to use pthreads with a decreased stack size. However, I do still have access to C++11, so I wanted to write something similar to `std::async` that would let me launch a pthread in detached state, and run any function, without returning a future. Essentially, std::async for functions that return void.

I came up with the following code, but it's really ugly, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to go about this.

```
static void* thread_start(void* args) {
    // Get the actual function
    std::function<void()>* f_ptr = static_cast<std::function<void()>*>(args);
    // Run the actual function
    (*f_ptr)();
    // Delete the function from the heap
    delete f_ptr;
    // Return nullptr, since we're not dinking around with futures
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void async(Function&& f, Args&&... args) {
    static size_t kStackSize = 1024*1024;
    // Allocate a std::function on the heap, so that we can call it safely after this stack frame is destroyed.
    std::function<void()>* f_no_args = new std::function<void()>;
    // Bind Args to Function, so that we have a void function
    *f_no_args = std::bind(f, args...);
    // Set up a new pthread with a smaller stack, and detached
    pthread_attr_t attr;    
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, kStackSize);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, &attr, &thread_start, f_no_args);
}
```

Comment: What happens if the thread isn't started before the stack frame is destroyed upon return from async? Won't the pointer become invalidated if it points to something on the stack?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably for the better. Better hope the function doesn't throw any exceptions or anything then.

Comment: Since you can implicitly convert a lambda that doesn't capture anything to a function pointer, you could move your `thread_start` function into such a lambda.  Unfortunately, since `pthread_create` takes a function pointer there's no way to usefully use a lambda that does capture anything, so you still need the heap allocation and static_cast.

Comment: Maybe more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com